# Column Reference During Count in SQL

Tags: sql

I wanted to clarify two things in this code below:

1. When using the number (1) in Count is that referencing the first column from benn.college_football_players database?
2. When using Group By 1, is that referencing to the cases that were created/  year_group or also the first column from the enn.college_football_players database?

   ```
     SELECT CASE WHEN year = 'FR' THEN 'FR'
            WHEN year = 'SO' THEN 'SO'
            WHEN year = 'JR' THEN 'JR'
            WHEN year = 'SR' THEN 'SR'
            ELSE 'No Year Data' END AS year_group,
            COUNT(1) AS count FROM benn.college_football_players
      GROUP BY 1
   ```

Comment: 1. It depends on DB engine implementation, `count(1)` or `count(*)` with both count the number of rows, `count(*)` may be slower than `count(1)` in Oracle if I remember correctly, but in other systems, it may be the same. In your query, you select 2 columns and it won't make a difference, it may make a difference in `select count(*) from table_with_many_columns` / `select count(1) from table_with_many_columns`

Comment: 2 you are grouping by `year_group` with `group by 1` in this case. you can group by column number or column name

Comment: actually, there is no difference between `count(1)` and `count(*)` in Oracle: "According to this question at AskTom there is no difference, and the optimizer actually changes count(1) to count(*) because the first means "count the rows where 1 is not NULL"

Comment: GROUP BY <column no> syntax is not supported by some implementations (SqlServer does not support it, for example)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? GROUP BY ordinal position is product specific.